# TD width not changing with input fields

Tags: html, css

My goal is to make each `TD` have a width of *100px* which should also make the input fields be *100px*. However, when I added `width="100"` to a `TD`, nothing happens. Here's the HTML code:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>2.</td>
        <td width="100">
            <input type="text" name="year2" id="year2" value="" />
        </td>
        <td width="100">
            <input type="text" name="make2" id="make2" value="" />
        </td>
        <td width="100">
            <input type="text" name="vin2" id="vin2" value="" />
        </td>
        <td width="100">
            <input type="text" name="radius2" id="radius2" value="" />
        </td>
        <td width="100">
            <input type="text" name="gvm2" id="gvm2" value="" />
        </td>
        <td width="100">
            <input type="text" name="comp2" id="comp2" value="" />
        </td>
        <td width="100">
            <input type="text" name="coll2" id="coll21" value="" />
        </td>
        <td width="100">
            <input type="text" name="amt2" id="amt2" value="" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here's a link to the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t691b9kq/)

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The style should be added on your `<input>` not on your `<td>`.  Also you should manage this via CSS instead of using inline styles.

In your CSS add

```
.my-width {
    width: 100px;
}
```

Then add that class to each of your inputs:

```
<input class="my-width" type="text" name="year2" id="year2" value="" />
```

**[JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/t691b9kq/3/)**

Answer (score 1):

Add `style="width: 100px"` to each `input` or add to your css file

```
input[type="text"]{
    width: 100px;
}
```

Here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t691b9kq/2/) for the second option